# Authorization error with Django on Windows with IIS

Tags: django, windows, iis, authorization

I am a medical physicist, trying to help a colleague set up a new installation of OpenREM version 1.0.0b2, an open source patient radiation dose management system ([openrem.org](https://openrem.org)). We have been following the documentation here: https://docs.openrem.org/en/1.0.0b2/install_windows.html.

The system is running on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

The OpenREM installation works perfectly when run using Django's built-in "python.exe manage.py runserver" command. However, it needs to be configured to run via Microsoft's IIS, and we cannot get this to work. There is an "Authorization" problem reported when I run "Test Settings" from the "Basic Settings" dialogue box in IIS:

[image]

We have tried giving the OpenREM application pool read access to the site, but this did not work.

Can any of you offer some help or advice with this?

I have a fully-working Windows server installation of OpenREM 1.0.0b2 at my workplace, so have some experience of installing and configuring the system, but IIS on my colleague's server has me stumped.

Many thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: You will have to ask the original developers to support you on the setup. Python virtual environment is known to be problematic, and wfastcgi has been deprecated by Microsoft. So this guide itself has many problems that only the developers can revise that and tell you what's the right way to go.

Comment: Dear Lex, many thanks for your comments. I am one of the OpenREM developers, but am not an IIS expert. None of my fellow developers have been able to help either, hence my question on here.

Comment: OK. That's a unique situation of its kind. But I doubt Stack Overflow is the right place for such, as fully resolving such requires hours of work and that's luxury. Ideally you might hire an experienced consultant.